# Compare two array has any one identical element in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, set, compare, contains

Need to compare the two array,
array1 = [1,2,3,4]
array2 = [1,5,6,7,8]
Result should in bool value.Need to check whether the  array1 contain any similar element in array2. So someone help me to solve the above problem.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this way will suit your needs:

```
let array1 = [1,2,3,4], array2 = [1,5,6,7,8]
let set1 = Set<Int>(array1), set2 = Set<Int>(array2)
let containsSimilar = set1.intersection(set2).count > 0
```

**Edit based on comments**

```
let array1: [Any] = [1,2,"a"], array2: [Any] = ["a","b","c"]
let set1 = Set<JananniObject>(array1.flatMap({ JananniObject(any: $0) }))
let set2 = Set<JananniObject>(array2.flatMap({ JananniObject(any: $0) }))
let containsSimilar = set1.intersection(set2).count > 0
```

Where `JananniObject` is:

```
enum JananniObject: Equatable, Hashable {

    case integer(Int)
    case string(String)

    static func ==(lhs: JananniObject, rhs: JananniObject) -> Bool {
        switch (lhs, rhs) {
        case (.integer(let integer0), .integer(let integer1)):
            return integer0 == integer1
        case (.string(let string0), .string(let string1)):
            return string0 == string1
        default:
            return false
        }
    }

    var hashValue: Int {
        switch self {
        case .integer(let integer):
            return integer.hashValue
        case .string(let string):
            return string.hashValue
        }
    }

    init?(any: Any) {
        if let integer = any as? Int {
            self = .integer(integer)
        } else if let string = any as? String {
            self = .string(string)
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But my array type [AnyObject].How to handle this .

Comment: Why do you use `AnyObject`?

Comment: Because by payload will be combined value i.e array1 = [1,2,"ABC"] or [1,2,3] or["a","b","c"]

Comment: The next time you ask a question - provide more details! Okay, only integer and strings? Or some other types might be in an array?

Comment: Only this two data types.

Comment: @JananniM check the edit. It might not work on swift version lower then 4. Anyway, the next time the question should contain more details. Hope it help

Comment: Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `Set`:

```
let one = [1, 2, 3]
let two = [2, 1, 3]
let three = [2, 3, 4]

print(Set(one).isSubset(of: two)) // true
print(Set(one).isSubset(of: three)) // false
```